# PHP. Как убрать определенные символы из строки запроса?

Tags: php

есть необходимость убрать некоторые символы из URL запроса, а именно знак ? и повторяющиеся слеши.

Предположим, что нужный мне URL сайта - это https://my-site.loc/
Пользователь может написать https://my-site.loc/api//user?
В этой ситуации мне необходимо будет провести редирект на https://my-site.loc/api/user, то есть без знака вопроса и дополнительных слешей.

Пробовал с помощью preg_replace('/(/){2,}/', '/', (наш URL))

Но проблема в том, что он удаляет и два слеша после HTTPS и редирект идет "внутрь" сайта.
Как можно удалить слеши, если их больше одного и знак вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант: если перед двойным слешем буквы или цифры, его заменить на одинарный. Например так:

```php
$str = 'https://my-site.loc/api//user?';

// так можно удалить слеши
// ищем те, перед которыми буквы и цифры
// и меняем на эту букву + 1 слеш
preg_replace('~(\w)//~', '$1/', $str);

// вместе с вопросами:
preg_replace(['~(\w)//~', '~\?~'], ['$1/', ''], $str);
```